# count odd and even digits in a number

Tags: c#

I try to write program that check the ratio between odd and even 
digits in a given number. I've had some problems with this code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int countEven = 0 ;
    int countOdd = 0 ;
    Console.WriteLine("insert a number");
    int num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    int length = num.GetLength;
    for (int i = 0;i<length ; i++)
    {
        if((num/10)%2) == 0)
        int countEven++;
    }
}
```

any ideas?

Comment: what problems have you had? stack trace?

Comment: What do you expect `int.GetLength` to do, and why do you expect it to be valid?

Comment: Use Math.Ceiling(Math.Log10(n)); to find the length of a integer.

Comment: Instead of parsing the input to int you'll need to treat the number as a string, so you can get the digits one by one

Comment: yeah, Jon Skeet I've noticed there is a problem with this line.

Comment: I tried to get the length of  num

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `int` does not have a length, only the string representation of it has one.As an alternative to m.rogalski answer, you can treat the input as a string to get all the digits one by one. Once you have a digit, then parsing it to `int` and checking if it is even or odd is trivial.Would be something like this:

```
int countEven = 0;
int countOdd = 0;
Console.WriteLine("insert a number");
string inputString = Console.ReadLine();
for (int i = 0; i < inputString.Length; i++)
{
    if ((int.Parse(inputString[i].ToString()) % 2) == 0)
         countEven++;
    else
         countOdd++;
}
```

Comment: You are absolutely right @fubo, but for a newbie i think my way is clearer :) It's obvious that OP does not have the differences between string and int very clear

Comment: probebly you're right, this is the straitest way - no need to `int.Parse` first and struggling with `number.length` afterwards

Answer (score 2):

`Linq` approach

```
Console.WriteLine("insert a number");
string num = Console.ReadLine(); // check for valid number here?
int countEven = num.Select(x => x - '0').Count(x => x % 2 == 0);
int countOdd = num.Select(x => x - '0').Count(x => x % 2 != 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume your input is : `123456`
Now all you have to do is to get the modulo from the division by ten : `int m = num % 10;`
After that just check if `bool isEven = m % 2 == 0;`
On the end you have to just divide your input number by `10` and repeat the whole process till the end of numbers.

```
int a = 123456, oddCounter = 0, evenCounter = 0;
do
{
    int m = a % 10;
    switch(m % 2)
    {
        case 0:
            evenCounter++;
            break;

        default: // case 1:
            oddCounter++;
            break;
    }
    //bool isEven = m % 2 == 0;
}while( ( a /= 10 ) != 0 );
```

[Online example](http://rextester.com/NMQOP4464)

Comment: You could make this clearer by incrementing `evenCount` and `oddCount` inside the loop according to `isEven`.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Added that, Thank you for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 1):

Made a small change to your code and it works perfectly

```
int countEven = 0;
int countOdd = 0;
Console.WriteLine( "insert a number" );
char[] nums = Console.ReadLine().ToCharArray();
for ( int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++ )
{
    if ( int.Parse( nums[i].ToString() ) % 2 == 0 )
    {
        countEven++;
    }
    else
    {
        countOdd++;
    }
}

Console.WriteLine($"{countEven} even numbers \n{countOdd} odd numbers");
Console.ReadKey();
```

What I do is get each number as a a character in an array `char[]` and I loop through this array and check if its even or not.

Comment: thanks for your help you really solve it. I have one more little problem, I need to return different chars for each case but there is a problems in the following lines, can you figure it out? if (countEven > countOdd) return "Z";
            else if (countEven > countOdd) return "E";
            else return "S";

Comment: Return to where @Jack2025? Don't you mean `Console.WriteLine("Z");` instead?

Comment: yeah, i need to put this code inside a function and than use return, thanks.

Comment: @Jack2025 That is true although I don't fully understand what you mean, if I solved it could you upvote my answer?

Comment: if i need to create a function that get the number and return those values, how do i do that?  

       
            if (countEven > countOdd) return "Z";
            else if (countEven > countOdd) return "E";
            else return "S";


          }

Comment: @Jack2025 If you want my help making a method that returns something you do need to join

Answer (score 1):

If the Input number is a 32-bit integer (user pick the length of the number)
if asked:

1. The number of even digits in the input number
2. Product of odd digits in the input number
3. The sum of all digits of the input number

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    int num = ConvertToInt32(textBox1.Text);
    int len_num = textBox1.Text.Length;
    int[] arn = new int[len_num];
    int cEv = 0; pOd = 0; s = 0;

    for (int i = len_num-1; i >= 0; i--) { // loop until integer length is got down to 1
        arn[i] = broj % 10; //using the mod we put the last digit into a declared array
        if (arn[i] % 2 == 0) { // then check, is current digit even or odd  
            cEv++; // count even digits
        } else { // or odd
            if (pOd == 0) pOd++; // avoid product with zero
            pOd *= arn [i]; // and multiply odd digits
        }
        num /= 10; // we divide by 10 until it's length is get to 1(len_num-1)
        s += arn [i]; // sum of all digits 
    }
    // and at last showing it in labels...
    label2.Text = "a) The even digits count is: " + Convert.ToString(cEv);
    label3.Text = "b) The product of odd digits is: " + Convert.ToString(pOd);
    label4.Text = "c) The sum of all digits in this number is: " + Convert.ToString(s);
}
```

All we need in the interface is the textbox for entering the number, the button for the tasks, and labels to show obtained results.  Of course, we have the same result if we use a classic form for the `for` loop like `for (int i = 0; and <= len_num-1; i++)` - because the essence is to count the even or odd digits rather than the sequence of the digits entry into the array

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string args[]) {
        WriteLine("Please enter a number...");
        var num = ReadLine();

        // Check if input is a number
        if (!long.TryParse(num, out _)) {
            WriteLine("NaN!");
            return;
        }

        var evenChars = 0;
        var oddChars = 0;

        // Convert string to char array, rid of any non-numeric characters (e.g.: -)
        num.ToCharArray().Where(c => char.IsDigit(c)).ToList().ForEach(c => {
            byte.TryParse(c.ToString(), out var b);
            if (b % 2 == 0)
                evenChars++;
            else
                oddChars++;
        });

        // Continue with code

    }
```

**EDIT:**
You could also do this with a helper (local) function within the method body:

```
static void Main(string args[]) {
        WriteLine("Please enter a number...");
        var num = ReadLine();

        // Check if input is a number
        if (!long.TryParse(num, out _)) {
            WriteLine("NaN!");
            return;
        }

        var evenChars = 0;
        var oddChars = 0;

        // Convert string to char array, rid of any non-numeric characters (e.g.: -)
        num.ToCharArray().Where(c => char.IsDigit(c)).ToList().ForEach(c => {
            byte.TryParse(c.ToString(), out var b);
            if (b % 2 == 0)
                evenChars++;
            else
                oddChars++;

            // Alternative method:
            IsEven(b) ? evenChars++ : oddChars++;
        });

        // Continue with code

        bool IsEven(byte b) => b % 2 == 0;
    }
```

> *Why am I using a byte?*

Dealing with numbers, it is ideal to use datatypes that don't take up as much RAM.
Granted, not as much an issue nowadays with multiple 100s of gigabytes possible, however, it is something not to be neglected.
An *integer* takes up 32 bits (4 bytes) of RAM, whereas a *byte* takes up a single byte (8 bits).

Imagine you're processing 1 mio. single-digit numbers, and assigning them each to integers. You're using 4 MiB of RAM, whereas the byte would only use up 1 MiB for 1 mio. numbers.

And seeming as a single-digit number (as is used in this case) can only go up to 9 (0-9), you're wasting a potential of 28 bits of memory (2^28) - whereas a byte can only go up to 255 (0-255), you're only wasting a measly four bits (2^4) of memory.

Comment: I'm all about reducing memory & processor usage... and don't know all the intricacies. How much could be saved if the original readline was saved directly as a char[] instead of a string, would it be the 20 bytes of string overhead?  You are already copying it into a char[] with the ToList and qualifying with IsDigit to only have values between 48 and 57. I would think the byte conversion would just be redundant

Comment: While I see your point, I saw it fit to add the information, as I've been in several discussions about this before. I deemed the information worth sharing, as someone learning a lower-level language on, say an Arduino, might look at the code, and might use portions of it in their code. Hence why I added "Granted, not as much an issue nowadays with multiple [...]"